# github org membership locked in private

Tags: github, github-organizations

[image]

i cant change private to public, even tho im the owner
its locked.

does anyone know how to change it ?

Comment: i tried with diff browsers too

Answer (score 0):

You can't make others' organization membership public, even if you are an owner of that organization.

They will need to do it themselves.